# how i can get only value from php file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
function send($message,$mobile,$sender)
{ 
  $url=file_get_contents("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.comm);
  //????
 }
```

Result of url is : 
Error : 0
MessageID : 1302490

1- How can I can get only the values of error & msgid from the result of the function ?

---

```
 function getDelivery($msgid)
 { 
 $url=file_get_contents("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com);
 // ????
  }
```

Result of url is : 
STATUS05: The message has been sent successfully ...

2- How can I can get only the status value like (01 02 03 04 05) from the result of the function ??

Comment: This question makes no sense. What is your function supposed to do? file_get_contents returns the contents of a url/file. It doesn't return a URL or a status or something...

Comment: this is a content from url :

Comment: Error : 0
MessageID : 1302490


how i can get only values of error & msgid from result from url??

Comment: Google: php regular expressions...

Comment: You need to do string manipulation. I suggest completely changing your question. Ask something like this instead: I have a string that says "Error : 0 MessageID : 1302490", how do I extract the value of Error and MessageID. Mentioning file_get_contents just confuses everyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st way, with `preg_match_all`, then run through the `$array` and extract all numbers:

```
$string='Error : 0 MessageID : 1302490';

preg_match_all('/[0-9]*/', $string, $array);

print_r($array);
```

2nd way, if your string always has the same structure and never changes:

```
$string='Error : 0 MessageID : 1302490';

$string_array=explode("MessageID : ", $string);

$error_string=$string_array[0];

$error=(int)str_replace('Error : ', '', $error_string);
$messageId=(int)$string_array[1];

echo $error.' '.$messageId;
```

I hope this helps you get a start point.